# Custom setter via Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Is there a way to modify the `@Setter` annotation to add some custom logic to all set methods built via lombok.

I have a class with the fields initialized with some default values. Now I only want to set the value in the fields if the value is not null.

Example, something that generates-

```
 public void setFoo(int foo) {
     if (foo != null) {
         this.foo = foo;
     }
 }
```

For example, if I am using the `@Setter` annotation on a Jersey Update Request class, instead of doing things like-

```
if (request.getFoo() != null) {
    this.foo = request.getFoo();
}
```

I should be able to directly do-

```
this.setFoo(request.getFoo());
```

with some results.

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding this answer since Sumeet's is outdated as of 2019.

You can provide your own getter or setter logic by simply writing your own methods.

```java
package com.example;

import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public class Foo {

    //Will not generate a getter for 'test'
    private String test;

    //Will generate a getter for 'num' because we haven't provided our own
    private int num;

    public String getTest(){
        if(test == null){
            throw new Exception("Don't mind me, I'm just a silly exception");
        }

        return test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant to use `Integer` instead of `int`, which does not allow null values and therefore solves your problem :)

In general, I would not recommend to change the logic of `setFoo`. Silently not setting `foo` on an arbitrary condition would expose its usage to bugs or at least misunderstandings.

My suggestion is to either use a custom method explicitly named `setFooIfNotNull(Integer foo)`. A possible alternative solution would be to mark the field `foo` with the annotation `@NonNull` to throw a NullPointerException in a case of null values.

From the Lombok `@Setter` annotation [documentation 'small print'](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html):

> Any annotations named @NonNull (case insensitive) on the field are
>   interpreted as: This field must not ever hold null. Therefore, these
>   annotations result in an explicit null check in the generated setter.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your own custom setter by commenting the @Setter & @Getter of lombok then uncomment it.Otherwise You can mark any method with @lombok.experimental.Tolerate to hide them from lombok.